# How to submit multiple checkbox values in Ajax Json to Flask?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, flask, checkbox

I want to be able to send a JSON dictionary of true or false values from multiple checkboxes.
Unfortunately, when I submit, whether checked or unchecked, the values sent to Flask are always "on", not true or false.
Can anyone please help? I'd be very grateful.

Here is my HTML/JQuery code

checkbox1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/neptune-icon2.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/neptune-icon2.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<title>Check Box 1</title>
</head>
<body>



<center>



<input type="checkbox" id="checking-1" checked="false">
<input type="checkbox" id="checking-2" checked="false">

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="grab-checkboxes">

</center>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).on("click", ".grab-checkboxes", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            // var info = $(this).parent().siblings('#checking-1').text();

            var dateArray = [];

            $('#checking-1').each(function () {

                var check1 = $(this).val();
                var check2 = $(this).parent().find('#checking-2').val();

                dateArray.push({ 'checking1': check1, 'checking2': check2 });

            });

            console.log(dateArray);

            console.log(dateArray.length);
            console.log(Object.keys(dateArray));



            var server = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";

            var appdir = "/grab_checkboxes"


            $.ajax({

                 type:"POST",
                 url: server + appdir,
                 data: JSON.stringify(dateArray),
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                 success: function(data){

                     console.log(data);
                    console.log("Checking...");
                 }
             });

            return false;

        });




</script>


</body>
</html>
```

my flask code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/checkbox1", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def checkbox1():


    return render_template("checkbox1.html")

@app.route("/grab_checkboxes", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def grab_checkboxes():



    print("Grabbing 1 or more checkboxes that are true!")

    data = request.get_json()


    print(data)


    return "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your jquery code. Change your jquery code like this:

```
...

$('#checking-1').each(function () {

    var check1 = $(this).is(':checked');
    var check2 = $(this).parent().find('#checking-2').is(':checked');

    dateArray.push({ 'checking1': check1, 'checking2': check2 });

});
...
```

This way the state of each checkbox is sent correctly.